# Typescript anonymous array as function parameter

Tags: typescript

I'm getting this error in Typescript 4.9.  I understand why I'm getting the error but I'm not sure how to get around it.  I've looked at nullish coalescing but that gives more errors.  The parameter will always be a two-dimensional array with one or more sets of data.

```
private CreatePlots(data: [] ) {
    let valData = data[0][0];
    let plotInfo = <EpmsPlotQueryData>data[0][1];
    GUI.setPopupMsg("Loading query data " + this._processResults + " of " + this._PlotQueryList.length);
    plotInfo.createPlots(valData);
}
```

The error I'm getting for both references to data;
[image]

[image]

I can change the function to have data defined as any to get past the errors i.e.

```
private CreatePlots(data)
```

but I would like to understand why I can't use an empty array like you can in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the exact type of the parameter, you should declare it like this:

`data: Array<[string, EpmsPlotQueryData]>` or `data: [string, EpmsPlotQueryData][]` (both are the same), which is an array of tuples.

```js
private CreatePlots(data: Array<[string, EpmsPlotQueryData]>) {
    let valData = data[0][0];
    let plotInfo = data[0][1];
    GUI.setPopupMsg("Loading query data " + this._processResults + " of " + this._PlotQueryList.length);
    plotInfo.createPlots(valData);
}
```

As for why you get the error:

- `data: any[]` this is an array of anything
- `data: [number, string]` this is a tuple, you are telling the compiler that `data[0]` is always number,  `data[1]`  is always string, and `data[2]` doesn't exist.
- `data: []` this is an empty *tuple*, you're telling the compiler that you'll get an empty tuple (an array which is **always** empty).

Comment: CreatePlots is called after receiving data from a web service call.   In this case data[0][0] would be a string and data[0]1] would be a "UserDefinedObject" EpmsPlotQueryData, in General the result from the webservice could be anything.  Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Then use `Array<[string, EpmsPlotQueryData]>` (an array of tuples) @MtnManChris
I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: the answer you supplied of an empty tuple is what I needed.  This is so unlike java script where [] is an array of anything.  I could specify but the results from the webservice for other calls can be of other object/types so the answer is to not specify a type.

Comment: They probably still share some common shape? Like `Array<[string, any]>`